# What is the origin of the word "pilko"?

Tags: etymology

*Pilko* isn't similar to the word in any other language I know. What is its origin?

Answer (score 9):

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pilko#Esperanto) it comes from the Polish *piłka* (pronounced [ˈpiwkä]), where it also means ‘ball’.

Answer (score 7):

It's from Polish *piłka* and Yiddish *pilke* - probably chosen over the alternatives to avoid collision with the word *balo*.

Comment: The Polish word stems from Latin _pila_, which can be seen as an additional source for _pilko_.